# Default value not working with ngModel but works on reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a **radio button group** component, and when I use `ngModel` the component's value is `null` even though by default it is set to `jkl`. When I use a reactive form, the value is the value of the `FormControl` which is `def` and it works.

I created this example component to test the value:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example-radio-group-forms',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RadioButtonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="exampleGroup">
      <radio-group formControlName="example" name="reactive-radio">
        <radio-button value="abc">ABC</radio-button>
        <radio-button value="def">DEF</radio-button>
      </radio-group>
      <p>Reactive Forms Result: {{ exampleGroup.get('example')?.value }}</p>
    </form>
    <radio-group [(ngModel)]="inputBinding" name="template-radio">
      <radio-button value="ghi">GHI</radio-button>
      <radio-button value="jkl">JKL</radio-button>
    </radio-group>
    <p>Template Driven Result: {{ inputBinding }}</p>
  `,
})
export class RadioGroupFormsExample {
  // This one works
  exampleGroup = new FormGroup({
    example: new FormControl('def'),
  });

  // This one doesn't
  inputBinding = 'jkl';
}
```

I then have these two components module which extend my `ValueAccessor` component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [RadioButton, RadioGroup],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatRadioModule],
  exports: [RadioButton, RadioGroup],
})
export class RadioButtonModule {}

@Component({
  selector: 'radio-group',
  template: `
    <mat-radio-group
      #radioGroup
      [(ngModel)]="value"
    >
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-radio-group>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./radio-group.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioGroup),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class RadioGroup<T = any> extends ValueAccessor<T> {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // ngModel = null
    // reactive form = 'def'
    console.debug(this.value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'radio-button',
  templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio-button.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioButton),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class RadioButton<T = any> extends ValueAccessor<T> {}
```

My ValueAccessor component then handles the `onChange`, `onTouch`, and `writeValue`.

```
@Component({ template: '' })
export class ValueAccessor<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() disabled = false;
  @Input() required = false;
  @Input() name = '';
  protected _value?: T;
  get value(): T | undefined {
    return this._value;
  }
  @Input()
  set value(value: T | undefined) {
    this._value = value;
    this.onChange(value);
    if (this.onTouched) {
      this.onTouched();
    }
  }
  protected onChange = (_: T | undefined) => {};
  protected onTouched = () => {};
  registerOnChange(fn: () => T): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => T): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  writeValue(value: T): void {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add log in writeValue function ? Can you try to add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" after the [(ngModel)]="inputBinding" ?

Comment: I get three outputs when it is in `writeValue()` in this order: `def`, `null`, and `jkl`, and the `ngModalOptions` has no effect on the element or not as I still get the same output.

Comment: Here is what I get when I put them in both `writeValue()` and `ngAfterViewInit()`: 
`writeValue def`,
`writeValue null`,
`afterInit def`,
`afterInit null`,
`writeValue jkl`

Comment: Adding this to the radio button component seems to work:
`ngDoCheck() { this.checked = this.value === this.radioGroup?.value; }`

Comment: I think it is conflict inside ValueAccessor class. The set value function and writeValue function.  Try to change the order of "radio-button", If the result is "ghi".

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosed in a settimeout the write value to "give time" Angular to draw the radio buttons

```
writeValue(value: T): void {
  setTimeout(()=>{
     if (value !== undefined) {
       this.value = value;
  }})
}
```